# Getting exception "IFeatureCollection has been disposed. Object name: 'Collection'." on updating session in .net core 3.1

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-3.1, session-state, httpcontext

I want to update session variable in .net core. when i click on Start action method in controller and set session using

```
HttpContext.Session().SetInt32("Percentage",10)
```

and then I'm calling some synchrounous method which takes 5 minutes. After method completion, I want to set session again

```
HttpContext.Session().SetInt32("Percentage",35)
```

but this time I'm getting the error like:

> {"IFeatureCollection has been disposed.
> Object name: 'Collection'."}

I'm getting the session from GetData() method which are calling in every 20 seconds from index.cshtml using ajax call.

HomeController:

```
    private async Task<IActionResult> Start(string token, string btnClick)
        {                                    
                            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Percentage",10);                    
            
                            //Getting user details.. that takes 5 minutes;
        
                            GetUserDetails();
                               
                            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Percentage", 35);
                            GetOtherData();
                            //Getting other data.. that also takes 5-10 minutes;
                            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Percentage", 55);
                            return View();
        }
```

GetData Method:

This method calling from index.cshtml every 20 seconds and get the session data

```
public JsonResult GetData()
        {
            
            var res1 = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Percentage") + "," + _appData.status + "," + SyncCheckvar;

            return Json(res);
        }
```

Index.cshtml:

Here is the javascript code where I'm getting data from controller method GetData() in every 20 seconds.

```
<script>
        var bar = $('#progress_bar');
        var percentage = null;

        function stopProgress() {
            clearInterval(progress);
        }

        //var progress = setInterval(function () {
        //    percentage++;
        //    if (percentage <= 100) {
        //        $('#progress_percentage').html(percentage + '%');
        //        if (percentage > 10) {
        //            bar.css('width', percentage + '%');
        //            console.log(percentage);
        //        }
        //    }
        var progress = $(document).ready(function () {
            window.setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")',
                    async: false,
                    type: "GET",
                        success: function (result) {
                            var res = result.split(',');
                            var res1 = res[0];
                            var res2 = res[1];
                            var res3 = res[2];
                            $("#progress_percentage").empty();
                            $("#progress_percentage").append(res1);
                            $("#text_container").empty();
                            $("#text_container").append(res2);
                            $("#syncstatus").empty();
                            $("#syncstatus").append(res3); 
                        },
                });
                percentage = $('#progress_percentage').html();
                //alert(percentage);
                if (percentage < 100)
                {
                    $('#progress_percentage').html(percentage + '%');
                    if (percentage > 10)
                    {
                        bar.css('width', percentage + '%');
                       // console.log(percentage);

                        if ($('#syncstatus').html() == "True")
                        {
                            if ($('#mainstart').is(':hidden'))
                            {
                                document.getElementById("syncbtndiv").style.display = "block";
                                //document.getElementById("mainstart").style.display = "block";
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    //stopProgress();

                    document.getElementById("loader_container").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("triggerdetailsdiv").style.display = "none";
                    //document.getElementById("mainstart").style.display = "none";

                    if ($('#syncstatus').html() == "True")
                    {
                        if ($('#mainstart').is(':hidden'))
                        {
                            document.getElementById("syncbtndiv").style.display = "block";
                        }
                    }
                }
            },20000);
        });

        $(window).on('load', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")',
                async: false,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {
                    var res = result.split(',');
                    var res1 = res[0];
                    var res2 = res[1];
                    $("#progress_percentage").empty();
                    $("#progress_percentage").append(res1);
                    $("#text_container").empty();
                    $("#text_container").append(res2);
                },
            });
            percentage = $('#progress_percentage').html();
            //alert(percentage);
            if (percentage < 100) {
                $('#progress_percentage').html(percentage + '%');
                if (percentage > 10)
                {
                    bar.css('width', percentage + '%');
                    // console.log(percentage);
                }
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("loader_container").style.display = "none";
                stopProgress()
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

            services
            // Use OpenId authentication
            .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            // Specify this is a web app and needs auth code flow
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
            // Add ability to call web API (Graph)
            // and get access tokens
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
            }, initialScopes)
            // Use in-memory token cache
            // See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/token-cache-serialization
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"));
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            // Require authentication
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
            // Add the Microsoft Identity UI pages for signin/out
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            //services.AddSingleton<AppData>();
            services.AddScoped<AppData>();
            services.AddScoped<HomeController>();

            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
            var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo($"{path}\\DataProtectionKeys\\Keys.xml"));

            
            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);//You can set Time   
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            
            services.AddMvc(options=>options.EnableEndpointRouting=false);                
                
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            loggerFactory.AddFile($"{path}\\SentimentLogs\\Sentiment_Log.txt");

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");              
            });
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
        }
    }
```

I think i'm missing something. Please help me to implement session correctly in .net core 3.1